# Create a hudson/jenkins job with a web-form upload

Tags: hudson, jenkins

I have a requirement to create a job where a web upload (IE a post with a file) is going to be required. Is there a way to do this? (I've tried searching the web). Note that the files in question could be very large.

Workflow (for clarity):
User clicks build in job menu, user can set parameters and make an upload, user clicks submit and job is built with that file as a source.

Other use case:
The job is started remotely with a POST operation to upload the file and set the parameters.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can create a [Parameterized Build](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build) in which there is a **File** parameter for the user to upload their file.

> File parameter allows a build to
>   accept a file, to be submitted by the
>   user when scheduling a new build. The
>   file will be placed inside the
>   workspace at the known location after
>   the check-out/update is done, so that
>   your build scripts can use this file.

Comment: Doh - it was right under my nose. Thanks. I already had other params.

Comment: Do we have any flag to check whether user has uploaded the file or not ?

Comment: I realize this is a couple years old, but i'm trying this to upload a file to the workspace but it's not working. The job succeeds but no file is uploaded.