# Jenkins Parameterized Build upload location

Tags: jenkins, hudson

I have written some bash scripts for some specific project based automation. I am using the Parameterized Build process for uploading a file as explained in this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970574/create-a-hudson-jenkins-job-with-a-web-form-upload).
The issue is that I need to access the uploaded file from the scripts, but I am unaware of the location its been placed after upload.

Jenkins hints that the location would be relative to the workspace. I am not sure of what the workspace, in terms of Jenkins means.
I tried a couple of options.. the trunk location, /users/$USER/workspace/, /users/$USER/workspace/[project_name]/

Could anyone help me with the same?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Workspace is usually under the 'jenkins' folder, separated by job-names.

- To *find* the exact location of your job's Workspace, 
  simply echo the value of that parameter in your job:
  `echo $WORKSPACE` (for Unix/Linux/Mac)
  `echo %WORKSPACE%` (for Windows)
- To *use* this location in your scripts, simply prepend it to the path of your file:
  `ls -l $WORKSPACE/myFile.txt`
  or
  `dir %WORKSPACE%\myFile.txt`

Note it gets a bit tricky if you try to access the results of **Job_AA** from **Job_BB**,
as each is sitting in a different Workspace.
(You can access the Workspace of other jobs, but now **Job_BB** is dependent on the **Name** of **Job_AA**,
which is bad.)

For that I suggest using a *shared location* for all build-results, outside of Jenkins.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins assumes that the path to the uploaded file will be prepended by the path to your build's workspace.  You can specify your file location as either `$WORKSPACE/path/to/file` (Jenkins populates $WORKSPACE with the appropriate path for each build) or just `path/to/file`