# Upload file from jenkins for testing

Tags: java, linux, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, jenkins-plugins

I have designed automation framework. I am using Jenkins on linux for client to make them easy to run test without any issue or technical knowledge.

Now thing is My all test cases are depends on Excel sheet. Getting data and then putting result into excel.

For now I suggest to client to upload and download excel by using FTP with Filezilla.

Is there any better plugin or way which allow client to upload and download excel file manually from jenkins interface?

I tried parameter build but seems either not helpful or I am missing something.

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970574/create-a-hudson-jenkins-job-with-a-web-form-upload

Answer (score 1):

They have specified a file parameter here https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build

Comment: I tried it but have one issue. For now I am specifying path of excel into my code like **File file = new file("/usr/local/test.xls")** , Now If I want parameterized build and upload excel then which path I should specify in code?

Comment: @HelpingHands it depends on the user running the jenkins slave. Or it could be better if you specify it as `File file = new File ("~/test.xls")`

Comment: @HarshavardhanKonakanchi - You Rock. It works. Thanks a lot.